# Formatar data com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Atualmente estou formatando um campo data com a seguinte mascara:

```
$("input[type='date']").mask('dD/mM/yYYY', {
    translation: {
        d: { pattern: /[0-3]/ },
        D: { pattern: /[0-9]/ },
        m: { pattern: /[0-1]/ },
        M: { pattern: /[0-2]/ },
        y: { pattern: /[1-2]/ },
        Y: { pattern: /[0-9]/ },
        Y: { pattern: /[0-9]/ },
        Y: { pattern: /[0-9]/ }
    }
});
```

Mas gostaria ao menos de pode impedir que na primeira ocorrência, se o dia começar com digito 3 permitir que o digito seguinte seja somente 0 ou 1, que resultaria nos dias 30 e 31.

Comment: Como assim na primeira ocorrencia? Primeira vez que o campo ganha foco..?

Comment: Voce nao pode mudar sua mascara para (d/mM/yYYY) onde d = [0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]?

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode mudar usar `D: {pattern: /[^3][0-9]|3[0-1]/}`, ou colocar um digito so na mascara e fazer uma expressao mais simples: `mask('d/mM/yYYY')` e usar `d: {pattern: /[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]/}`.